# How to Run a Python File on Files with Different Character Encoding

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, encoding, character-encoding

So I have files that have different encodings. And I am doing `find *.srt -type f -exec python3 ../file.py {} \;` to run my code to these files.

Because these files have different encoding my code does not work. I simply have too many files. How can I run my code to every file without making any errors. When I run my code now, codecs is not able to open these files or just assigns wrong character.

```
AmericanDreamsS01E17_en.srt:                        Little-endian UTF-16 Unicode text, with CRLF line terminators
The_Last_Mimzy_en.srt:                              Non-ISO extended-ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
Everybody_Hates_Chris_S04_E06_en.srt:               ISO-8859 text, with CRLF line terminators
Blackish_S01_E24_en.srt:                            OS/2 REXX batch file, UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) text, with CRLF line terminators
Coyote_Ugly_en.srt:                                 Non-ISO extended-ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
Coyote_Ugly_en.txt:                                 UTF-8 Unicode text, with very long lines, with no line terminators
Crash_en.srt:                                       UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) text, with CRLF line terminators.
Weeds_S02E12_en.srt:                                C++ source, UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) text, with CRLF line terminators
Weeds_S02E12_en.txt:                                UTF-8 Unicode text, with very long lines
WeWereSoldiers_en.srt:                              ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
WeWereSoldiers_en.txt:                              UTF-8 Unicode text, with very long lines, with no line terminators
Without_A_Paddle_en.srt:                            UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) text, with CRLF line terminators
```

my code is below

```
import sys
import re
import string
import codecs

def del_brackets(s):
        a = re.compile(r'\<.*?\>')
        result = a.sub('', s)
        return result.strip('\n').strip()

with codecs.open(sys.argv[1], 'rb', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

outfile = codecs.open(sys.argv[1].replace('.srt', '.txt'), 'w')

exclude = set('♪"#$%&\()*+-/:<=>@[\\]^_`{|}')
for line in lines:
#   print(repr(line))
    line = line.strip()
    #line = unicode(line.strip('\n'), 'utf-8')
    if len(line.strip()) != 0 and line != 1 and line != "1":
        if (not line.isdigit()) and ('-->' not in line):
            line = del_brackets(line)
            line = ' '.join(''.join(' ' if ch in exclude else ch for ch in line).split())
            line = re.sub(r'\.\.\.', ' ', line)
            outfile.write(line.lstrip() + "\n")

outfile.close()
```

So each file contains a something looks like the following.

```
1
00:00:17,284 --> 00:00:19,418
Bravo!

2
00:00:19,486 --> 00:00:22,388
Bravo, Manny,
bravo!

3
00:00:22,456 --> 00:00:24,023
Well, when I heard
Manny wanted to fence,
```

and the correct output must look like

```
Bravo!
Bravo, Manny,
bravo!
Well, when I heard
Manny wanted to fence,
```

But some files include weird characters and I keep getting

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 797: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: All your files is utf8 compatible. What is the point in opening file in read bytes mode? Why do you need to specify encoding if you're reading it as bytes?

Comment: @Javed because there are files that have ```utf-16le``` encodings... such as there are so many files with different encodings. Codecs would just throw an error saying that it cannot decode a character at some location.

Comment: @Javed I added more examples

Comment: And what exactly are you trying to accomplish? Unfortunatly there is no way to guess encoding of a file and be 100% sure that you guessed right. So knowing the exact task might help with the solution.

Comment: @Javed I have edited my post

Comment: If we look at the format of srt file - we can see that each subtitle ends with the newline symbol which indicates the end of the subtitle. So the solution might be as simple as:
go to the end of file and read up to 2 repeating bytes (which is newline itself and linefeed from previous line). Now you get linefeed sequence, go to the start of a file and do the split by linefeed, removing unnecessary lines (following .srt specs)
If your task is to convert encodings - then, as I said, you can't be sure in guessing encodings